# triangle, square, retractable, polygon, circle, eclipse in 2d. pyramid, cube, box, what for polygon, sphere, ellipsoid in 3d. what tesseract in 4d?...

Tags: geometry, terminology, dimensional-analysis

What is a corresponding shape's name in 3d, 4d and is 5d have some name for it:

```
2d: triangle, square, retractable, polygon, circle, eclipse
3d: pyramid, cube, box, what for polygon, sphere, ellipsoid 
4d: tesseract, what are rest?
5d: is some name here also
6d:
..
..
nd:
```

is something infinite dimension that exists?

Comment: Are you sure that an eclipse belongs to this list ? :)

Comment: Most names are the usual 3D (or 2D) names prefixed by "hyper", for example sphere $\to$ hyper-sphere, ellipsoid $\to$ hyper-ellipsoid... In some other cases, for example the sphere in nD, one meets also names such as "the $n$-sphere".

Comment: The first one in each list is called "simplex".

Answer (score 2):

Name of the polygon in $3$-dimension are:
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~$tetrahedron, Hexahedron, octahedron, Dodecahedron, Icosahedron, polyhedron etc.
[List of regular polytopes and compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regular_polytopes_and_compounds#Four_dimensions)

The prefix "hyper-" is usually used to refer to the four- (and higher-) dimensional analogs of three-dimensional objects, e.g., hypercube, hyperplane, hypersphere. n-dimensional polyhedra are called polytopes.

The four-dimensional cases of general $n$-dimensional objects are often given special names, such as 
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~$glome, tesseract, pentatope, polychoron, hyperplane, 16-cell, facet, content etc.

For more details you may see the following references:
[Four-Dimensional Geometry](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Four-DimensionalGeometry.html#:%7E:text=The%20prefix%20%22hyper%2D%22%20is,%2C%20hypercube%2C%20hyperplane%2C%20hypersphere.&text=%2Ddimensional%20objects%20are%20often%20given,summarized%20in%20the%20following%20table.)
[Viewing Four-dimensional Objects In Three Dimensions](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/forum/polytope/)

General $n$-dimensional objects:
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~$hypersphere, hypercube, simplex, polytope, hyperplane, cross polytope, facet, content etc.

For more details you may see the following references:
[Higher Dimensional Polytopes](https://blogs.ams.org/mathgradblog/2016/06/18/higher-dimensional-polytopes/)
[Shapes, Fractals, Time &, the Dimensions they Belong to](https://wewanttolearn.wordpress.com/2017/10/18/shapes-fractals-time-the-dimensions-they-belong-to/)
[Exotic Objects from Higher Dimensions](https://www.maynoothuniversity.ie/research/research-news-events/latest-news/exotic-objects-higher-dimensions)

Comment: The OP is also missing the 3D equivalent of polygon, which is polyhedron.

Comment: Thanks for your indication. I have already made the necessary modification of my answer.